# function for binning data based on date values

Tags: python, pandas, date, bin

I am writing a function to bin data based on the number of months in the entire history of the data set.

Here's the data I am working with:

```
month = pd.date_range(start = "2016-01-03", freq = "6D", periods = 100) 
quarter = pd.date_range(start = "2016-03-01", freq = "28D", periods = 50) 
year = pd.date_range(start = "2016-03-01", end = "2022-08-09", freq = "9D") 

small = pd.DataFrame(month, columns = ["date"]) # < 27 months, use month boundaries
medium = pd.DataFrame(quarter, columns = ["date"]) # >= 27 & < 48 months, use quarter boundaries
large = pd.DataFrame(year, columns = ["date"]) # > 48 months use year boundaries
```

The logic of the function works like this:

- If the number of months is > 48, use calendar year boundaries to bin the data
- If the number of months is >= 27 and < 48, use quarterly boundaries to bin the data
- If the number of months is < 27, use month boundaries (e.g., 2016-03 to 2018-09)

The function **must be able to bin the data into 3 bins**

This is what I have of the function so far:

```
def time_cohort(df):
    
    #Obtain the length of the data set in months
    months = len(pd.date_range(start = df["date"].min(), end = df["date"].max(), freq = "M"))

    if months > 48: #use calendar year boundaries
        chosen_period = "year" 
        frequency = "Y"
        dates = pd.date_range(
            start = df["date"].min(), end = df["date"].max(), freq = "Y"
        )
    
    elif months >= 27 and months < 48: #use quarterly boundaries
        chosen_period = "quarter"
        frequency = "Q"
        dates = pd.date_range(
            start = df["date"].min(), end = df["date"].max(), freq = "Q"
        )
    
    else: #use month boundaries
        chosen_period = "month"
        frequency = "M"
        dates = pd.date_range(
            start = df["date"].min(), end = df["date"].max(), freq = "M"
        )
    
    #number of bins is always three
    bins = 3
    edges = np.linspace(start = dates[0].value, stop = dates[-1].value, num = bins + 1)
    dates = pd.to_datetime(edges)

    df["date_group"] = pd.cut(
        df["date"], bins = dates,
        labels = ["Earliest", "Middle", "Latest"],
        right = False,
        include_lowest = True
    )

    df[chosen_period] = df["date"].dt.to_period(frequency)

    summary = df.groupby(by = "date_group", as_index = True)\
    .agg({chosen_period:[min, max], "date_group":pd.Series.count})\
    .reset_index(None)\
    .droplevel(level = 0, axis = "columns")\
    .rename(columns = {"":"date_group", 
                       "min":"earliest {}".format(chosen_period),
                       "max":"latest {}".format(chosen_period)})

    return summary
```

If I were to run the function on a large data set (i.e., months > 48), the output would look like this:

| date_group | earliest year | latest year | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Earliest | 2016 | 2018 | 68 |
| Middle | 2018 | 2020 | 67 |
| Latest | 2020 | 2022 | 65 |

I have two problems:

- The first problem is that the date boundaries are overlapping, therefore some observations belong to two groups (an observation must belong to one group only). How can I ensure that the bin boundaries do not overlap?
- The second problem is that not all of the observations are binned. The observations that are not being binned belong to date values which are the earliest and latest date values respectively - for example if I ran the following code on the medium data set:

```
#apply function medium data set
time_cohort(medium)

#check for missing values (that is, un-binned values)
medium[["date_group", "quarter"]].loc[medium["date_group"].isna() == True].drop_duplicates()
```

The following is returned:

| date_group | quarter |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 2016Q1 |
| NaN | 2022Q4 |

These actually correspond to the minimum and maximum date boundaries:

```
[medium["quarter"].min(), medium["quarter"].max()]

#output
[Period('2016Q1', 'Q-DEC'), Period('2019Q4', 'Q-DEC')]
```

What is going on here for this to occur?

I have the majority of what I need to do,  I just need help tying up these loose ends

Answer (score 0):

I have found a function that works:

```
I have found a way that works:

def time_cohort(df):
    """
    The function takes in a data-frame as an input and creates a column
    whereby parts of the data are categorised based upon which 'date bin'
    they fall into.

    The way in which the data is binned depends upon the total 
    number of months in the data set. The logic of this 'binning'
    of the data is as follows:

    * if the total number of months is > 48, the data is binned by calendar year boundaries
    * if the total number of months is >= 27 & < 48, the data is binned by quarter boundaries
    * if the total number of  months is < 27, the data is binned by month boundaries

    The data is then binned into three categories based upon these boundaries
    """

    #obtain number of months in the data set
    months = len(df["start_date"].dt.to_period("M").unique())

    if months > 48: #use calendar year boundaries
        chosen_period = "year" 
        frequency = "A-DEC"
    
    elif months >= 27 and months < 48: #use quarterly boundaries
        chosen_period = "quarter"
        frequency = "Q-DEC"
    
    else: #use month boundaries
        chosen_period = "month"
        frequency = "M"
    
    #chopping up the data into bins
    dates = []
    start = df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).min()
    dates.append(np.datetime64(start))

    while start < df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).max():

        #floor division by 3 ensures that there are 3 (approximately) equal intervals
        start = start + (len(df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).unique()) // 3)
        dates.append(np.datetime64(start))

        #this ensures that the groups labels are one fewer than the number of bins
        while len(dates) > 4:
            del dates[-1]
    
    #the latest date in the list of dates should be the maximum date
    dates[-1] = np.datetime64(df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).max())

    df[chosen_period] = df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency)
    df["group"] = pd.cut(
        df["start_date"], bins = dates,
        labels = ["Earliest", "Middle", "Latest"],
        include_lowest=True
    )

    #Accounting for uncategorised observations
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        period = row[chosen_period]

        if period == df[chosen_period].min():
            df.loc[i, "group"] = "Earliest"
        
        elif period == df[chosen_period].max():
            df.loc[i, "group"] = "Latest"
        else:
            pass
    
    summary = df.groupby(by = "group", as_index = True)\
        .agg({chosen_period:[min, max], "group":pd.Series.count})\
        .reset_index(level = None)\
        .droplevel(level = 0, axis = "columns")\
        .rename(columns = {"":"group", 
                       "min":"earliest {}".format(chosen_period),
                       "max":"latest {}".format(chosen_period)})

    return summary
```