# Tweak "time-grouping" function pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This question relates to a previous post which I answered myself recently which can be found here: [function for binning data based on date values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75598405/function-for-binning-data-based-on-date-values)

The function I have written works except that it has a slight problem in that the number of observations per bin is uneven - across the data sets I have tested it on, more often than not, there are fewer observations in the "Earliest" bin than in the "Middle" and "Latest" bins.

I thought to compensate for the lack of observations, I would *widen the bin* that defines the "Earliest" bin (that is, I would define the "Earliest" bin by **increasing the difference between the minimum and maximum dates it is defined by**). Consequently, the "Middle" and "Latest" bins would have smaller bins. This doesn't have to be perfect, the number of observations in each bin just has to be approximately equal

Could anyone show me where in the body of the function I could add some code that would achieve this?

Here is some exemplar data:

```
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.date_range(start = "2015-09-13", periods = 200, freq = "13D")
df = pd.DataFrame("start_date":start_date})
```

And here is the function:

```
def time_cohort(df):
    """
    The function takes in a data-frame as an input and creates a column
    whereby parts of the data are categorised based upon which 'date bin'
    they fall into.

    The way in which the data is binned depends upon the total 
    number of months in the data set. The logic of this 'binning'
    of the data is as follows:

    * if the total number of months is > 48, the data is binned by calendar year boundaries
    * if the total number of months is >= 27 & < 48, the data is binned by quarter boundaries
    * if the total number of  months is < 27, the data is binned by month boundaries

    The data is then binned into three categories based upon these boundaries
    """

    #obtain number of months in the data set
    months = len(df["start_date"].dt.to_period("M").unique())

    if months > 48: #use calendar year boundaries
        chosen_period = "year" 
        frequency = "A-DEC"
    
    elif months >= 27 and months < 48: #use quarterly boundaries
        chosen_period = "quarter"
        frequency = "Q-DEC"
    
    else: #use month boundaries
        chosen_period = "month"
        frequency = "M"
    
    #chopping up the data into bins
    dates = []
    start = df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).min()
    dates.append(np.datetime64(start))

    while start < df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).max():

        #floor division by 3 ensures that there are 3 (approximately) equal intervals
        start = start + (len(df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).unique()) // 3)
        dates.append(np.datetime64(start))

        #this ensures that the groups labels are one fewer than the number of bins
        while len(dates) > 4:
            del dates[-1]
    
    #the latest date in the list of dates should be the maximum date
    dates[-1] = np.datetime64(df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency).max())

    df[chosen_period] = df["start_date"].dt.to_period(frequency)
    df["group"] = pd.cut(
        df["start_date"], bins = dates,
        labels = ["Earliest", "Middle", "Latest"],
        include_lowest=True
    )

    #Accounting for uncategorised observations
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        period = row[chosen_period]

        if period == df[chosen_period].min():
            df.loc[i, "group"] = "Earliest"
        
        elif period == df[chosen_period].max():
            df.loc[i, "group"] = "Latest"
        else:
            pass
    
    summary = df.groupby(by = "group", as_index = True)\
        .agg({chosen_period:[min, max], "group":pd.Series.count})\
        .reset_index(level = None)\
        .droplevel(level = 0, axis = "columns")\
        .rename(columns = {"":"group", 
                       "min":"earliest {}".format(chosen_period),
                       "max":"latest {}".format(chosen_period)})

    return summary
```

The output for this function looks something like this:

```
time_cohort(df)
```

| group | earliest year | latest year | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Earliest | 2015 | 2017 | 65 |
| Middle | 2018 | 2019 | 56 |
| Latest | 2020 | 2022 | 79 |

Notice how there is **no overlap** between the group boundaries - this is absolutely crucial

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I get [65, 56, 79] when running your code. Also, it is expected that not all bins will contain the same number of observations since you limit the bins to containing full year/quarter/months. In your example, you cannot make the 'Latest' bin smaller, as it contains only the last year, so you cannot make it smaller if you want to work with whole years.

Comment: @Filip thank you for your reply, sorry I made a couple mistakes which I have fixed. It is quite difficult to replicate the data I am working with (i.e., trying to replicate a situation where there would be fewer observations in the "Earliest" bin). Do you think there could be a way to ensure that the difference between the first and second elements in the "dates" list is greater than the other differences between consecutive elements to ensure that the "Earliest" bin is wider?

Comment: Are you even sure that your code does not work as expected? I mean, to me it seems like it is doing what you want it to do. If you want the difference in counts to be smaller, I guess you will have to allow for the bins to have boundaries at quarters or months. If you think it is not doing what you want, then you have to show an example where the expected and actual behaviours differ.